# How to update order data after payment from paypal?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, payment, paypal, sales

I am using Magento 1.7 version and having issue while updating data of order after make payment from PayPal.

I have an event `sales_order_invoice_pay` which works on invoice generate. When I make a payment from PayPal, it generates an invoice of order placed then this event calls.

```
<sales_order_invoice_pay>
      <observers>
          <test>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>test/observer</class>
              <method>getInvoice</method>
           </test>
       </observers>        
</sales_order_invoice_pay>
```

Then, I have a field in `sales_flat_order` table which I want to update using

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orders->setFieldId($fieldId);
```

I have value of both $orderId and $fieldId.

But it is not updating. It shows blank. I think this is due to PayPal IPN which overwrites the value of my field.

> Is there any event for updating this value?
>
> Any event which trigger after PayPal IPN received?
>
> Any event which trigger after order detail email sent to customer?
>
> Any idea which solves above issue?

Comment: Just a clue but do you $orders->save(); after your code to actually save your changes? .... Events can be found here: http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Comment: @StefanGregori You can write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a clue but do you $orders->save(); after your code to actually save your changes?

You can find a list of available Events here:
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/